# Button Click Not a Function

Tags: php, html, ajax, button

I have inserted a delete button in every row of my HTML data table. On the button click, I want to delete the row. However, my delete button does not fire the JS function.

I attempted `button.setAttribute` and `button.onclick` but they are null.

```
function MakeTable(iArray)
{
    var myArray = [];
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for(var i = 0; i< iArray.length; ++i)
    {
        myArray[i] = iArray[i];
        btn = document.createElement('button');

        btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btn.setAttribute('class','Delete');
        btn.setAttribute('id', myArray[i].userID);

        btn.innerHTML = "Delete" + btn.getAttribute('id');

        let row0 = table.insertRow();
        let blankCell = row0.insertCell(0)
        let cell0 = row0.insertCell(1);
        let cell1 = row0.insertCell(2);
        let cell2 = row0.insertCell(3);
        blankCell.appendChild(btn);
        cell0.textContent = myArray[i].userID;
        cell1.textContent = myArray[i].username;
        cell2.textContent = myArray[i].password;

    }
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', DeleteUsers());
}

function DeleteUsers()
{
   alert("clicked!");
}
```

The alert shows on page reload, but not on clicking any of the buttons.

Comment: you are assigning the onclick outside of the loop. So at most it will be attached to 1 element. And if you place it INSIDE the loop, be sure you understand about closures. Look it up. :-)

Comment: How is this a "php" question? There's also no "html" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `onClick` since it is insecure and simply buggy. Instead, try using `$('.class').on('click', function(){ DeleteUsers() }` if your're using jQuery or in case you're using vanila JS:

```
document.getElementByClassName('class').addEventListener('click', function () {
  DeleteUsers();
});
```

Comment: Should I assign the onclick outside of my for loop? Or on my document.ready?

Comment: Outside of the loop if you want to assign it to the whole class. Preferably in `document.ready` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick', DeleteUsers());
```

This line executes the DeleteUsers() method at the moment you are asigning it to 'onclick'

try

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick', DeleteUsers);
```

This way you only pass a pointer to the method instead of calling it right away.